# Continuous function and function relationship

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity, functional-equations

I have a function relationship and I know that this function is continuous in a specific $x_0$. I know how to prove that this function is continuous at $D_f$.

I have the function relationship:
$$f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)-\sin(x)\cdot \sin(y), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$ This function is continuous in $x_0=0$ and I want to prove that $f$ is continuous at $\mathbb{R}$. But for $x=y=0$ I get two different values for $f(0)$. So how to prove what I want?

Answer (score 2):

*One way is to find explicitly the function(s) that satysfies a condition:*

If we put $x=y=0$ we get $f(0)=f(0)^2$ so $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$.

Say $f(0)=0$, then we have, for $y=0$: $$f(x) = f(x)f(0)-0 =0\;\;\;\forall x$$ which is clearly not a solution.

---

So $f(0)=1$.

For $x=\pi/2 =-y$ we have $$1= f(0)= f({\pi \over 2})f(-{\pi \over 2}) +1 \implies f({\pi \over 2})=0\;\;\;{\rm or}\;\;\;f(-{\pi \over 2}) =0$$

a) if $f({\pi \over 2})=0$ we have $$f({\pi \over 2}-x) = f({\pi\over 2})f(-x) +\sin({\pi\over 2})\sin (x)= \sin (x)$$

so if we replace ${\pi \over 2}-x$ with $x$ we get $f(x) = \cos(x)$ which is clearly continuous.

b) if $f(-{\pi \over 2})=0$ we have $$f(-{\pi \over 2}+x) = f(-{\pi\over 2})f(x) +\sin({\pi\over 2})\sin (x)= \sin (x)$$

so if we replace ${-\pi \over 2}+x$ with $x$ we again get $f(x) = \cos(x)$,